# How to check if parent element in html is specific tagname (e.g. span) using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to check if the parent element is a span.  How can I do that using Javascript (not JQuery)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
element.parentNode.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'span'
```

Comment: Should have `...toLowerCase()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myElement"),
    isParentSpan = elem.parentNode.tagName === "span";

alert( isParentSpan );
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember that .nodeName returns an UPPERCASE string (with some exceptions). It's safest to toLowerCase() when you compare.

http://ejohn.org/blog/nodename-case-sensitivity/

```
var el = document.getElementById('test'),
    parent = el.parentElement || el.parentNode,
    parentType = el.parentElement.nodeName.toLowerCase();

if ( 'span' === parentType ) {
    alert('Parent is a span!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TT6jr/